# Link multiple tables from one database

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have actually this little function working as supposed:

```vb
Function createAttached(strTable As String, strPath As String, strBaseTable As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo CreateAttachedError

    Dim tdf As TableDef
    Dim strConnect As String
    Dim fRetval As Boolean
    Dim myDB As Database

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    Set myDB = CurrentDb
    Set tdf = myDB.CreateTableDef(strTable)

    With tdf
        .Connect = ";DATABASE=" & strPath
        .SourceTableName = strBaseTable
    End With

    myDB.TableDefs.Append tdf
    myDB.TableDefs.Refresh

    fRetval = True

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

CreateAttachedExit:
    createAttached = fRetval
    Exit Function

CreateAttachedError:
    If Err = 3110 Then
        Resume CreateAttachedExit
    Else
        If Err = 3011 Then
            Resume Next
        Else
            If Err = 3012 Then
                Set tdf = myDB.TableDefs(strTable)
                tdf.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & strPath
                tdf.RefreshLink
                fRetval = True
                GoTo CreateAttachedExit
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

This code works fine, I can call the function as many times as I want to add links to tables from another database. However, I have about 30 tables to import from the same database and this script restarts from scratch everytime I call it. Because the database is located on another server, it takes about 1 min to link the 30 tables.

Is there anything I could do with that function to make it work faster when I need to link multiple tables from the same database? I would like it to work with multiple strTable and strBaseTable in parameters instead of one (maybe arrays?), but I don't know how to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the tabledefs collection in the external database or use a table of tables that lists all the tables to be connected and the external database.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim ThisDb As Database

Set ThisDb = CurrentDB
sDb = "z:\docs\test.accdb"
Set db = OpenDatabase(sDb)

For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    ''Connect
    If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
        If IsNull(DlookUp("Name","MsysObjects","Type In (1,4,5,6) And Name='" _
           & tdf.Name & "'")) Then
           DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", _
             sDb, acTable, tdf.Name, tdf.Name
        Else
          If ThisDb.TableDefs(tdf.Name).connect <> vbNullString Then
             ThisDb.TableDefs(tdf.Name).connect = ";DATABASE=" & sDb
             ThisDb.TableDefs(tdf.Name).RefreshLink
          End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

A table of tables would work in a similar fashion in that you can select the database (select distinct) from the table and loop through that recordset attaching the tables in a further selection (select table where database ...)

Comment: Not sure how it would work. If you look at my above code, it's the line `myDB.TableDefs.Append tdf` that takes 3 seconds to run. What I want is `myDB.createTableDef()` and `tdf.SourceTableName` to support multiple entries. I don't understand how to implement the loop you're talking about.

Comment: I have added some notes. To link server tables see http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Link_All_SQL_Server_Tables

Comment: Doesn't this code loop .Append? This is actually what is taking 3 seconds.

Comment: Well, I just tried back the 30 calls to my original createAttached() function and it now takes less than a second (about ~50ms per table). I guess it really depends on the server's response, but if there would be a way to avoid calling .Append so many times, it would be perfect. Also, working with the 3012 error isn't optimal, I guess there is some way to check if the table already exists before trying to link it.

Comment: That's different from the link you posted from lessthandot. I will try it and get back here after to tell you if I got it working that way.

Comment: another thing that I see, my .mdb file grows by ~800KB each times I (re)link the tables. A little bit annoying, isn't it? I'm talking about the file where the links are, not the file with the original tables.

Comment: The database is automatically compacted once a week with another VBS script, it should be okay. It seems like the size doesn't grow when the link is actually okay, even if I still call .RefreshLink, so it's all right.

Comment: Tested and it works. But this code doesn't refresh the existing links. Any easy way to do it?

Comment: I see. I will test this when I will be back at my office tomorrow. Thank you again, I've been able today to do a lot with LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN in SQL, thanks to the help you gave me on another question. I've been reading a lot on the Web too about the differences between inner and outer joins, but I'm the kind of guy that likes to learn when doing it in a real situation.

Comment: CurrentDB doesn't support .Connection? However the code does run without that additional if(), the .RefreshLink is executed but nothing really happens, the link isn't in fact refreshed.

Comment: np, but this code still does nothing. It runs, but the link's path isn't refreshed. The condition is met, the .RefreshLink runs, but it does nothing.

Comment: I mean change to a new link, ya. My initial code in my initial post up there does change the link if the link already exists (error 3012).

Comment: But doesn't it force the code to access the .mdb file 20 times if there are 20 tables in that database?

Comment: I tried `CurrentDb.TableDefs(tdf.Name).Connect = ";DATABASE=" & strPath` before the .RefreshLinks. It runs but doesn't refresh the link. It's kind of frustrating.

Comment: Option explicit is there and strPath in my code is a string containing the full path to the database it must links to. I finally made it working but it's not really elegant. I end up using .Connect for each links, which was the purpose of my initial question (not using .Connect 20 times and save some time).

Comment: Nah, it's still an acceptable answer as it still accelerates the creation of the links when they don't exist. As I can see, there is no way to do the same to change the links. Delete the links is also one by one as far as I know and it's even longer (I tried with DoCmd.DeleteObject).

Answer (score 0):

What you could also do is set up the database connect in a different sub as well as the database disconnect (which I might be missing here?).

So then the code that calls this script normally (I assume you have a loop) will look like this:

`call function/sub that opens the connection to DATABASE= strPath`

`your loop that calls Function createAttached`

`call function/sub that closes the connection to DATABASE= strPath`

That way you avoid the repetitive (usually time consuming) connection to the external database